# How to send custom parameter along with reserve event to firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am able to send custom parameter along with custom event to firebase analytics in android using below method :-

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Action", "Action Perform Android");
                bundle.putString("Category", "CustomEvent Android");
                bundle.putString("Label", "click me");
                firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Button_clicked", bundle);
```

Above method is working and we can see this event on firebase console.

[Here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) are some event that event name is reserve and we can not use this name again to send event to Firebase analytics like `notification_dismiss`, `notification_open` etc. These predefined events are automatically collected by Firebase.

Now I want to send some custom parameter along with these above event.
For example when `notification_open` event fired, I want to add notification title as a custom parameter along with this event. How can we override `notification_open` event or how can we set notification title custom parameter along with this event in `android`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add custom parameters to events that are automatically sent. You will have to define your own event to add those parameters to.

Once you've done that, you can combine the standard and custom event in BigQuery, to get both the default and the custom parameters in a single report.

Comment: How can i send more than 10 textual custom parameters to firebase analytic?

Comment: Can you please tell me that, Can I send more than 10 textual custom parameters to firebase analytic?